# Como puedo implementar axios en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws

Estoy realiando un proyecto de la escuela en react donde tengo que aplicar el CRUD, pero estoy teniendo unas dificultades al momentos de hacer las peticiones desde mis componentes usando como ejemplo mi componente eliminar, me recomendaron usar axios pero estoy teniendo muchos problemas al querer implementarlo.
lo que hice primero fue hacer una conexión a mi BD desde un js el cual cree en una carperta llamada Server dentro del src, aqui esta el codigo:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Configuración de la conexión a la base de datos
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'AWS',
    user: 'admin',
    password: '123456789',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'restaurante'
});

// Conexión a la base de datos
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error al conectar a la base de datos: ', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Conexión exitosa a la base de datos');
});
```

el cual mi base de datos lo tento en aws, aquí ya comprobé la conexión y llegue a hacer unas opciones de agregar y eliminar y funcionaron perfectamente.

ahora lo que quiero hacer es hacer la coneccion desde un componente llamado EliminarProducto el cual esta dentro de una carpeta llamada Components dentro del src
aqui les muestro un ejemplo de como lo tengo:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Styles/EliminarPlatillo.css';
const axios = require('axios');


const EliminarPlatillo = () => {

    const [producto, setProducto] = useState('');
    const [productoEncontrado, setProductoEncontrado] = useState(''); 

    const buscarProducto = () => {
        // aqui tenemos que poner la logica para la basew de datos

        if (producto == "nada"){
            alert('no existe');
        } else{
            setProductoEncontrado(producto); //solo puse prodcuto para que que si funciuone
        }

    };

    const confirmarEliminacion = () => {
        // aqui va la logica para eliminar desde base de datos
        alert('eliminado');
    };

    return (
        <div className="eliminar-platillo-container">
            <div className="eliminar-platillo-left">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={producto}
                    onChange={(e) => setProducto(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del producto"
                />
                <button onClick={buscarProducto}>Buscar</button>
            </div>
            <div className="eliminar-platillo-right">
                <p>{productoEncontrado}</p>
                <button onClick={confirmarEliminacion}>Confirmar Eliminación</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EliminarPlatillo;
```

aqui es donde ya he descargado lo necesario para usar axios, pero hasta aqui me llegue a quedar, La informacion de mi base de datos que tengo es, nombre de BD: restaurante el cual tiene una tabla llamada menu y tine nombreplatillo, quisiera saber como puedo hacer las solicitudes desde este componente.

Comment: No es recomendable llamar a la base de datos directamente desde react... debes hacer una API que se encargue de hacer las llamadas a la base de datos... y react se comunicaría con esa API